# HC-06 (BC 417) how to disconnect to activate something

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno

I was working on a project that involves using the HC-06, and the aim was to turn the led on when the bluetooth and my phone are far apart enough to disconnect. But I have no idea how to do it.

Here's the code I'm using on Arduino:

```
while (Serial.available()) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
};
```

So I know here's the problem but I've search everywhere online and I have no idea how to activate the led as soon as they disconnect.

Please be descriptive because I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

To activate the LED just do:

`digitalWrite(13, HIGH);`

To detect when the bluetooth is disconnedted just refer to this question.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175083/can-i-tell-if-the-hc-06-bluetooth-is-connected

Basically you have two options:

- Hardware solution: one option is to connect the status LED of the HC06 to an input pin on the Arduino and read it to determine if the LED is blinking or steady.
- Software solution: Send an `AT` commend and check if you receive an `OK` back (not paired) or nothing back (paired)

By the way, It's strange that you haven't found anything after "searching everywhere online" since it just took 10 seconds to google search and find a solution.